# Accessing image in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, resources

I added an image in my Visual Studio project and I am trying to access it in my XAML resource dictionary without specifying the complete path to where it is on my hard drive.

```
<ImageBrush x:Key="image" ImageSource="Cherries.jpg"></ImageBrush>
```

Comment: And what's the problem? Error?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf).

Make sure that the `Build Action` of the image is set to its default value of `Resource`.

You can specify a path like this where you replace "Subfolder" with the name of the folder within your project where the image resource resides:

```
<ImageBrush x:Key="image" ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Subfolder/Cherries.jpg" />
```

If you have put the image in the root folder the path would be:

```
<ImageBrush x:Key="image" ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Cherries.jpg" />
```

If it is located in another assembly, you inlcude the name of this one:

```
<ImageBrush x:Key="image" ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/Cherries.jpg" />
```

Comment: Note however that in XAML you can omit the prefix and just write `ImageSource="/Subfolder/Cherries.jpg"`